# Supervisord error "child process was not spawned"

Tags: python, bash, supervisord

I create bash to run python script `start_queue.sh`

content of start_queue.sh

```
python /tmp/my_python_script.py &
```

It's work when I run it in terminal. But I want to manage it using supervisord since I have few django website already manage by supervisord.

But I just get the error when start

```
supervisor: couldn't exec /tmp/start_queue.sh: ENOEXEC
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

This is how i config in supervisord

```
[group:scriptgroup]
programs=script_1

[program:script_1]
command=/tmp/start_queue.sh
directory=/tmp/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/x.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=50
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_events_enabled=false
loglevel=info
```

It's possible to manage a backgroup process by supervisord, What did i wrong here. Please help.

Comment: The error message seems to imply incorrect permissions.

Comment: I was getting such error until changed line endings style of the *.sh file from CRLF to LF

Comment: I was having a different problem when a process was being launched and got the `EACCES` error. By adding the `directory=/tmp/` in the program section I was able to solve my problem. Thank you for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add #!/bin/sh at the beginning of script.

Comment: sometimes it works wihtout this, and sometimes it needs this. any specific reason for this?

Comment: agreed, what is the explanation of this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your `shell script` `spawned`. `Spawn` means when you kill it, it doesn't kill unless a set of cicumstances to be.

notes: `supervisor` is a python module that control proocessing.
[For more see this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219013801/http://stackful-dev.com/simplify-unix-process-herding-with-supervisor.html).